# Problema en Android Studio, al momento de hacer el cambio de layout con el raddio button la aplicación se cierra en el celular

Tags: java, android, android-studio

```
package com.example.marcelosegovia.servicioswebunid;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

/**
 * Created by Marcelo Segovia on 15/11/2017.
 */

public class AgregarContactoActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

    Intent ventana;
    String usuario;

    EditText nombre;
    EditText apodo;
    EditText movil;
    EditText casa;
    EditText email;
    Button guardar;

    String IP = "http://192.168.1.7/agenda";
    String INSERT = IP + "/insertar_contacto.php";

    ObtenerWebService hiloconexion;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_agregar_contacto);

        Bundle datos = getIntent().getExtras();
        usuario = datos.getString("nombre");

        nombre = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.nombre);
        apodo = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.apodo);
        movil = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.movil);
        casa = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.casa);
        email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
        guardar = (Button)findViewById(R.id.guardar);

        guardar.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        hiloconexion = new ObtenerWebService();
        hiloconexion.execute(INSERT,"5",nombre.getText().toString(),apodo.getText().toString(),
                movil.getText().toString(),casa.getText().toString(),email.getText().toString());



    }

    public class ObtenerWebService extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            String cadena = params[0];
            URL url = null; // Url de donde queremos obtener información
            String devuelve ="";

            try {
                HttpURLConnection urlConn;

                DataOutputStream printout;
                DataInputStream input;
                url = new URL(cadena);
                urlConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                urlConn.setDoInput(true);
                urlConn.setDoOutput(true);
                urlConn.setUseCaches(true);
                urlConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
                urlConn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
                urlConn.connect();
                //Creo el Objeto JSON
                JSONObject jsonParam = new JSONObject();
                jsonParam.put("nombre", params[2]);
                jsonParam.put("apodo", params[3]);
                jsonParam.put("movil", params[4]);
                jsonParam.put("casa", params[5]);
                jsonParam.put("email", params[6]);
                // Envio los parámetros post.
                OutputStream os = urlConn.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                        new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
                writer.write(jsonParam.toString());
                writer.flush();
                writer.close();

                int respuesta = urlConn.getResponseCode();

                StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

                if (respuesta == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

                    String line;
                    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConn.getInputStream()));
                    while ((line=br.readLine()) != null) {
                        result.append(line);
                    }

                    //Creamos un objeto JSONObject para poder acceder a los atributos (campos) del objeto.
                    JSONObject respuestaJSON = new JSONObject(result.toString());   //Creo un JSONObject a partir del StringBuilder pasado a cadena
                    //Accedemos al vector de resultados

                    String resultJSON = respuestaJSON.getString("estado");   // estado es el nombre del campo en el JSON

                    if (resultJSON == "1") {
                        devuelve = "Contacto guardado correctamente";

                    } else if (resultJSON == "2") {
                        devuelve = "El contacto no pudo guardarse";
                    }

                }

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return devuelve;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCancelled(String s) {
            super.onCancelled(s);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            verifica(s);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        }
    }

    public void verifica(String s){

        if (s.equals("Contacto guardado correctamente")  ){

            Toast.makeText(this, nombre.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Toast.makeText(this, "Ha sido registrado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            ventana = new Intent(AgregarContactoActivity.this, keyActivity.class);
            ventana.putExtra("nombre", usuario);
            startActivity(ventana);

        }else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "No se pudo completar el registro", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            nombre.setText("");
            apodo.setText("");
            movil.setText("");
            casa.setText("");
            email.setText("");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Te recomiendo mejorar tu pregunta, lee la siguiente guia: [ask]

Comment: ¿Revisaste el `LogCat`? Es una herramienta que te va a ahorrar horas y hasta días de depuración... Revísalo y agrega la información del error [editando tu pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/120378/edit). En cuanto a la pregunta, tal como la has planteado, nos obligas a leer todo tu código, a adivinar su lógica y a adivinar dónde haces el cambio que dices que te está fallando. Puesto que tú conoces todo eso, podrías al menos decir, *creo que me está fallando aquí*, o bien: *es aquí donde hago el cambio problemático**, etc. Mientras más claro seas, tendrás respuestas más eficaces.

Comment: muchas gracias, pude resolverlo era un error en esta parte del codigo Bundle datos = getIntent().getExtras();
        usuario = datos.getString("nombre");

Answer (score 0):

esta parte del código era el error : Bundle datos = getIntent().getExtras();
        usuario = datos.getString("nombre");

yo no estaba mandando nada en mi switch case, solo estaba invocando de una activity a otra y como el activity no encuentra el valor, se crashea[![Estas dos imágenes son de mi código, en la primera la cual tiene un radio button en la parte que esta seleccionado con azul, es la activity que al momento de cargar el apk en el celular y seleccionarla se crasheaba.
en la segunda imagen esta la parte del codigo que especifique mas arriba en la cual se encuentra el error.][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZHDa.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZHDa.png).

Gracias !

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: esta es la del error]